# Web2py - Oracle Connection Failure

Tags: python, oracle, web2py

I'm trying to connect web2py to my my local Oracle DB, installed the `cx_Oracle` from pip3 and installed [Oracle Instant Client](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#oracle-instant-client-zip-files).

```sh
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client64/lib:
```

Web2py version `Version 2.19.1-stable+timestamp.2020.03.21.13.06.49`.

My db.py, file

```py
db = DAL('oracle://username/password@test')
```

but got this error:

```
<class 'RuntimeError'> Failure to connect, tried 5 times: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/user/project/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/base.py", line 507, in __init__ self._adapter = adapter(**kwargs) File "/home/user/project/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/__init__.py", line 41, in __call__ obj = super(AdapterMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/user/project/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 417, in __init__ super(SQLAdapter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/user/project/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 85, in __init__ self.find_driver() File "/home/user/project/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 134, in find_driver "No driver of supported ones %s is available" % str(self.drivers) RuntimeError: No driver of supported ones ('cx_Oracle',) is available
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you could re-post this but making sure that the stack trace is printed over its original multiple lines, that would be more useful.

Comment: Getting to the end of the stack trace I see

    RuntimeError: No driver of supported ones ('cx_Oracle',) is available

Do you see `libclntsh.so` in `/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib` ? Does your user have permission to load it? Apart from that, it appears that web2py needs some other configuration steps done, but I don't know off-hand what they might be.

Comment: `libclntsh.so` has `777`, 

user@user:/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client64/lib$ ls -lah libclntsh.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 may 27 00:36 libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.19.1

Comment: (i) don't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, since the equivalent is already set up by the Instant Client 19c RPMs. (ii) does a simple cx_Oracle test application run OK (i.e. one without Web2py)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client64/lib` in `ld.so.conf` file:

```sh
#vim /etc/ld.so.conf
/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client64/lib
```

Then:
`sudo ldconfig`

Comment: This isn't needed: the 19c RPMs run `ldconfig` during install.   See https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/oracle-instant-client-19c-for-linux-is-available